# Get метод класса вызывает исключение с#

Tags: c#, .net, исключения, методы

только начал учить c# и решил сделать для класса get методы и set методы
Использу visual studio 2022

-------------------файл класса------------------

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Project1
{
    public class human
    {
        public int Age 
        {

            set
            {
                if (value > 0)
                {
                    Age = value;
                }
            }

            get 
            {
                
                return Age; //System.StackOverflowException: "Exception_WasThrown"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

------------------------файл с main классом------------------

```
using Project1;

namespace project
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            human gu = new human();
            int age = gu.Age;
            Console.WriteLine(age);
            
        
            
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Тут и геттер, и сеттер, бесконечно вызывают сами себя. Значение надо же реально хранить где-то.

Comment: Запомните, что get и set это просто методы. А что будет если метод бесконечно будет сам себя вызывать? Будет ваш вопрос на StackOverflow, под которым вы прочитаете этот комментарий, в котором написано...